# Binding in behavior to datacontext of datatemplate in silverlight

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, datatemplate, behavior

I have a DataTemplate:

```
  <Style x:Key="SalesmanDestinyReportListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdSalesmanDestinyReport" Width="180" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="False" IsFilteringAllowed="True"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Scores}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                           <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <Binding:ColumnGroupsBehavior>
                                    <Binding:ColumnGroupsBehavior.CommonHeaders>
                                        <Binding:CommonHeader StartColumnIndex="0" Caption="{Binding Path=DataContext.SalesmanName,ElementName=grdSalesmanDestinyReport}" ColumnSpan="3" />
                                    </Binding:ColumnGroupsBehavior.CommonHeaders>
                                </Binding:ColumnGroupsBehavior>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Current}" IsReadOnly="True"
                             Header="{Binding Current}" Width="60">
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Current}">

                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Destiny}" IsReadOnly="True"
                             Header="{Binding Current}" Width="60">
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Destiny}">

                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Best}" IsReadOnly="True"
                             Header="{Binding Current}" Width="60">
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Best}">

                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

                            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                        </telerik:RadGridView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

here is a source class:

```
public class SalesmanDestinyReport
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Score> Scores { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string SalesmanName { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have a problem with this piece of code:

```
                       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <Binding:ColumnGroupsBehavior>
                                <Binding:ColumnGroupsBehavior.CommonHeaders>
                                    <Binding:CommonHeader StartColumnIndex="0" Caption="{Binding Path=DataContext.SalesmanName,ElementName=grdSalesmanDestinyReport}" ColumnSpan="3" />
                                </Binding:ColumnGroupsBehavior.CommonHeaders>
                            </Binding:ColumnGroupsBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The problem is that I can't pass SalesmanName  property to

```
   <Binding:CommonHeader StartColumnIndex="0" Caption="{Binding Path=DataContext.SalesmanName,ElementName=grdSalesmanDestinyReport}" ColumnSpan="3" />
```

I think that there is no need to explain wthat's the CommonHeader, because the problem I believe lays in another place, but just in case:

http://blogs.telerik.com/pavelpavlov/posts/09-12-04/adding-additional-power-to-radgridview-for-silverlight-with-attached-behaviors.aspx

What I need to change in my binding declaration to display SalesmanName  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From scratch - Silverlight 4 does not support bindings in Style Setters (this functionality is now available in SL5). For SL4 there is a workaround: [SetterValueBindingHelper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/07/one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better.aspx).